# Command substitiution problem, confused

Tags: command-line, bash, sound, sox

I am trying to have sox play a file from user input. To do this, I set up a command like the one below:

```
$ play proc/$(read -n 1).wav
```

I have files 0.wav through 9.wav located in the directory proc. I can play one of them like the example below:

```
$ play proc/4.wav
```

However, when I try to do it with user input, I press the number 4 and this is what it outputs:

```
4play FAIL formats: can't open input file `proc/.wav': No such file or directory
```

Any ideas? I'm confused.

Answer (score 3):

I think the problem you are having is that the bash read command doesn't write the result to stdout, it stores the results in variables, either named ones passed as arguments, or in the REPLY variable.

So for instance, I think what you want here is something like:

```
read -n1 track
play "proc/$track.wav"
```

You can see all the details by typing `help read` in bash.

Comment: For good practice, you should use lowercase variable names, and quote variable expansions. `read -n1 track && play "proc/$track.wav"`

Comment: @geirha good point, I'll update the answer, thanks